# Ractive render on change stops jquery slideDown

Tags: jquery, ractivejs, materialize

I'm using Ractive to render a list of messages, like this:

```
<ul  class="collapsible">
    {{#each messages}}
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header" on-click="readNotification">{{#if read}}<span>{{title}}</span>{{else}}<strong>{{title}}</strong>{{/if}}</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <p>{{body}}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

No problem there, but when the list item is clicked it needs to slide open and I will set the message as read. This triggers Ractive to re-render that node preventing it from opening.

How is this best dealt with?

**EDIT:**
The data in ractive is updated by this callback, that listens to the child_changed event from Firebase. I then set the updated object to its index location in the ractive object. ractive probably sees this as a new object instead of an updated one?

```
this.firebase.child(collectionKey).on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
    var collectionKey = snapshot.ref().parent().key();
    var obj = snapshot.val();
    var key = snapshot.key();
    var index = app.ractive.get(collectionKey).map(function(item) { 
        return item._firebaseKey;
    }).indexOf(key);
    app.ractive.set(collectionKey+'.'+index, obj);
});
```

Comment: It shouldn't be re-rendering the node... can you provide a working demo? It might be better to use https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive-transitions-slide

Comment: @RichHarris thanks for the quick reply and all the work you put in to make this library intuitive. It'd take too long for me to provide you with a working version but I was missing some important info. The code that updated the data. Hopefully your able to help me out with this edit.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this some days ago by creating a proper 'Decorator'. I find the Decorators implementation to be more dependable than firing jQuery code at the DOM by listning to change events from Ractive.

Decorators are easy to create, check out: http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/writing-decorator-plugins